# How can I tell when avd is completely launched?

Tags: android, bash, jenkins, android-virtual-device, calabash-android

I'm running a jenkins job that starts an avd device and uses calabash-android to run tests against it.

```
emulator -avd phone
```

How can I tell when this device is completely started so that I know I can start the tests without getting a device connection error?

I tried

```
adb wait-for-device
```

but that won't work because according to the adb [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

> "Note that this command does not cause adb to wait until the entire system is fully booted. For that reason, you should not prepend it to other commands that require a fully booted system."

Right now I have a hard sleep, what would be a better way to script this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are launching your tests via adb.  If so, adb supports wait-for-device to block until the device is available (online).

```
adb wait-for-device
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out. The command I was looking for was

```
adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed
```

The full script for using the avd tool with jenkins looks like this (note: the output is all pumped into a textfile so that it doesn't tie up the script, there's probably a better way to handle this part of it)

## Launch the sim

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/emulator -avd phone -gpu on -memory 2500 1>~/test.txt 2>&1 &
```

## Wait for the sim to finish launching

```
A=$($ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r')
while [ "$A" != "1" ]; do
sleep 2
A=$($ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb shell getprop sys.boot_completed | tr -d '\r')
done
```

## Unlock sim

```
$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb shell input keyevent 82 1>~/test.txt 2>&1 &
```

Comment: You may also sometimes have to wait for the "android.process.acore" process to finish starting before you can install any APKs, otherwise it will just. The Android Emulator Plugin for Jenkins should have this feature in the next release.